# i corrected this error INTERNAL SERVER ERROR and after deployed i'm not able to see the output

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

https://memories-creator-app.herokuapp.com/posts

[Heroku logs]

2020-11-10T04:38:25.201691+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com
2020-11-10T04:38:25.201691+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com
2020-11-10T04:38:25.379000+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com
2020-11-10T04:38:25.379000+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com
2020-11-10T04:39:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com
2020-11-10T04:40:00.402571+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com
2020-11-10T04:40:00.402571+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 412ce8cd by user smileyshivam3042@gmail.com

2020-11-10T04:40:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-10T04:40:03.125983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2020-11-10T04:40:06.486822+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-10T04:40:06.486851+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-10T04:40:06.486852+00:00 app[web.1]: > node --experimental-modules index.js
2020-11-10T04:40:06.486852+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-10T04:40:06.548164+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader
is experimental.
2020-11-10T04:40:07.195099+00:00 app[web.1]: server runing on port: 5705                          is experiment
2020-11-10T04:40:07.365282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

Comment: What is the functionality of that GET method? Update your question with that implementation.

Comment: I think you should change the start script and use node not nodemon, your code won't change once deployed.

Comment: @BawanthaWickramarachchi I corrected internal server error but stuck with another thing that i can't see my output   https://memories-creator-app.herokuapp.com/posts    if possible plz suggest me how to correct it

Comment: @Smiley Shivam, can you update the answer with log output given now. Literally, this output you have right now means that your entire program is not working. So, again you need to go through the log files.